# Custom Login and Registration for new WordPress users

Tags: wordpress, authentication, buddypress

I'm fairly new at WordPress, therefore hopefully someone will find it easy enough to share a few minutes of their time assisting me. Basically, I was trying to implement custom registration into my new WordPress install. After struggling for a while, I came by the BuddyPress plugin, which seems to be absolutely amazing, except for one thing - while the registration works perfectly well, in order to login you apparently either need to have a wordpress account (there's the wordpress logo, etc). Would there be any hints on what actions could I take now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use WordPress with both the BuddyPress and Theme My Login plugins. This would let you completely customise the login and registration pages of WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

This IMHO is the classic online tutorial for customised login/register/password retrieval for Wordpress.

http://digwp.com/2010/12/login-register-password-code/

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.